# Confusion in solving $(D^2+a^2)y= \tan ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(D^2+a^2)y= \tan ax$

I know the complete integral. I have a confusion regarding particular integral(PI).

$$\text{PI} = \frac 1{D^2+a^2}\tan ax = \frac 1 {2ai} \left(\frac 1 {D-ai}-\frac 
1 {D+ai} \right) \tan ax $$

Considering, $\frac 1 {(D-ai)} \tan ax = $(I got following answer)$$ = e^{aix} \left(\frac{-1} a \cos ax -\frac i a \ln |\sec ax + \tan ax| + \frac i a \sin ax \right) $$

Now for other part i.e., $\frac{1}{(D+ai)} \tan ax$, without calculating, in textbook i have seen he replaced $i$ with $-i.$ I got a doubt - why cannot $a$ with $-a$???? when i solved,  i got that solution which is $i$ replaced with $-i$? How did he get intuition that it must be i replaced with $-i$ and not $a$ replaced with $-a.$

Kindly enlighten

Comment: I’m not clear on what you are solving for. Or are you trying to evaluate an integral?

Comment: particular integral. Complete solution has 2 parts - complete integral and particular integral right